# How can I manually copy over files like LXDE and other apps?

Tags: networking, 10.04, lxde

I have a really old laptop which I have recently installed Lucid 10.04.4 Server on because it would not support newer versions. Instead of an ethernet cable it has an internal modem with a phone line connection on the outside. It was designed for Windows 98! I cannot work out how to fix my wifi adaptor in terminal. I really want to have a desktop enviroment or at least a window manager with which to manually launch my apps on. How can I carry over files from my internet connected ubuntu 13.10 laptop to this old one and get them working?
Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that you can simply carry over the .deb files on a usb and use dpkg -i to install them. This worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

Download, burn and install Lubuntu from an alternate install disk. You will find all the information needed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO